# Shopify closing cyle-tag

Tags: shopify, cycle

I'm trying to achieve to close an cycle-tag after an iteration over a collection has finished.

```
<div class="row products">
    {% for product in collection.products limit: settings.pagination_limit %}
    {% cycle '<div class="row">', '', '', '' %}
    {% include 'product-loop' with collection.handle %}
    {% cycle '', '', '', '</div>' %}
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
```

I know about using cycling groups, but I don't know how to use it here.
After iterating over a collection a new cycling group should be used.

I tried using this what isn't working:

```
{% cycle [collection.handle]: '<div class="row">', '', '', '' %}
```

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work without the square brackets. Try this:

```
{% cycle collection.handle: '<div class="row">', '', '', '' %}
```